# Decomposing $(x^2-y,z-1)$ into primary ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

As the title suggests, I would like to decompose the ideal $I:=(x^2-y, z-1)\vartriangleleft k[x,y,z]$ into primary ideals.

I suspect it may be prime already, if $I= \ker G$, where $$G: k[x,y,z] \to k[s], \\  f(x,y,z) \mapsto f(s,s^2,1).$$

At least we must have $I \subseteq \ker G$, since $x^2 -y \mapsto s^2 -s^2 =0$ and $z-1 \mapsto 1-1 =0$. Does the converse inclusion hold?

If not: how would I go about decomposing this ideal?

Comment: Geometrically speaking the quotient is the ring of functions on the parabola $y=x^2$ embedded in the plane $z=1$ which looks pretty irreducible to me ...

Comment: I agree on the geometric intuition, but I have heard that algebraic geometry can sometimes be unintuitive. (I'm currently in my second week studying the subject...) - How can we make the intuitive argument rigorous?

Comment: If we have affine varieties $X_1, X_2$, when is $X_1 \cap X_2$ an affine variety?

Comment: If one uses the well known isomorphism $R[T]/(T-a)\simeq R$, where $R$ is a commutative ring, $a\in R$, and $T$ is an indeterminate, then your quotient ring is isomorphic to...

Comment: @user26857 how does this apply? Maybe I could use $R/(I+J) \simeq R/I \otimes_R R/J$, then apply what you wrote. Still I would need to figure out $k[x,y,z]/(x^2-y)$? Hmm, I guess that would work, though, if I view $x^2-y$ as an element of $k[x,z][y]$. But then I will have to deal with the tensor product.

Comment: Well, seems like it follows from the third isomorphism theorem almost instantly, using $R[T]/(T-a) \simeq R$. Thank you very much for your help.